# Issue with getting parts of a svg displayed

Tags: css, svg

I'm dealing with some messy SVG code and have an issue with displaying icons on a product page.

This is how the icon should look:

[image]

Here is how it gets displayed with the drops missing ([link to product page](https://langerchen.com/collections/fa2020-wollmaentel-damen/products/c035ws01-classical-coat-ii-carbon)):

[image]

I inspected the code in the browser, and tried different things like setting the elements fill to a specific color etc. But even in the dev tools I wasn't able to set the color of the element in the dev tools with e.g. `element.style{fill: red!important;}`. I don't understand, where it gets overwritten.

I'd be grateful if someone can point me to the right direction.

[image]

Comment: I suppose it's because you have the svg elements styled with classes and thus one svg style is overwritting the styles for the drops. Y would remove the style element inside the svg elements and use attributes or styles in the html document

Comment: But I don‘t understand why it‘s getting overwritten even when I use !important

Comment: @zinyosrim It could be specificity issues

Comment: This is what I would do: 1. remove all the unused paths: those with display:none. 2. delete the styles inside the svg elements. 3. create common styles for the svg elements and add those styles to the html document or to an .css file. You have lots of useless styles like fill:red that you don't need. Simplify your code by getting rid of the useless things

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself i.e. not a link to your website and not an image of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to `display:none;` or remove/comment of 2nd `<g>` inside `<g id="Illu">`. Attached screenshot will help you more.

[image]

**Updated code of `<g id="Illu">` :-**

```
 <g id="Illu">
      <g>
        <defs>
          <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="2.8" y="2.8" width="70.9" height="70.9"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <path class="st1" d="M38.3,72.7c19,0,34.4-15.4,34.4-34.4c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4S3.8,19.3,3.8,38.3
                        C3.8,57.3,19.3,72.7,38.3,72.7z"></path>
        <path class="st2" d="M19.3,37.3c3.6,0,6.6-2.9,6.6-6.6c0-3.6-5-9.5-6.6-13.9c-1.6,4.4-6.6,10.3-6.6,13.9
                        C12.8,34.3,15.7,37.3,19.3,37.3z"></path>
        <path class="st2" d="M33.7,43.6c2.6,0,4.7-2.1,4.7-4.7s-3.5-6.8-4.7-9.9c-1.1,3.1-4.7,7.3-4.7,9.9S31.2,43.6,33.7,43.6z"></path>
      </g>
    <!--  <g>
        <defs>
          <rect id="SVGID_3_" x="2.8" y="2.8" width="70.9" height="70.9"></rect>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
        </clipPath>
        <path class="st3" d="M38.3,72.7c19,0,34.4-15.4,34.4-34.4c0-19-15.4-34.4-34.4-34.4S3.8,19.3,3.8,38.3
                        C3.8,57.3,19.3,72.7,38.3,72.7z"></path>
      </g>-->
      <rect x="2.8" y="2.8" class="st4" width="70.9" height="70.9"></rect>
      <g>
        <path d="M12.5,61.1c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,1.9,2h47.7c0.7-0.6,1.3-1.3,1.9-2H12.5z"></path>
        <path d="M57.5,66.8c0.9-0.6,1.8-1.3,2.7-2H16.3c0.9,0.7,1.7,1.4,2.7,2H57.5z"></path>
        <path d="M57.7,23.3V35h2V23.3c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.1S58.1,23.3,57.7,23.3z"></path>
        <path d="M46.3,9.5h-12v2h11.9c0-0.2,0-0.5,0-0.7C46.2,10.4,46.2,10,46.3,9.5z"></path>
        <path d="M49.1,18.8l-8.8,8.8l1.4,1.4l8.8-8.8C50,19.8,49.5,19.3,49.1,18.8z"></path>
        <path d="M58.7,21.4c-5.8,0-10.5-4.7-10.5-10.5c0-1.8,0.5-3.6,1.3-5.1c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.4-1.9-0.6c-0.7,1.4-1.2,2.8-1.3,4.4
                        c0,0.4-0.1,0.9-0.1,1.3c0,0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7c0.2,2.7,1.2,5.3,2.8,7.3c0.4,0.5,0.9,1,1.4,1.4c2,1.7,4.5,2.9,7.3,3.1
                        c0.3,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.1s0.7,0,1-0.1c3-0.2,5.6-1.5,7.6-3.4c-0.4-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.1-1.7C64.3,20.1,61.7,21.4,58.7,21.4z"></path>
      </g>
      <line class="st5" x1="65.8" y1="58.3" x2="10.4" y2="58.3"></line>
    </g>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Priya. May I ask, how you discovered this was the issue?

Comment: When I inspected and saw both drop element is here but not visible. So, I guess a layer is overlapping which should be in code after both drop element. Thus i detected this issue :).